# Woocommerce product variations: Change position of „in stock“

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

As you know, the product variation templates are looking a little bit different as the normal single product template.

The in stock specification is shown under the price on the variations, not in the near of the add-to-cart button as normal.

**How can I change the position/order of the in stock? I want to show the in stock after the add-to-cart-button.**

Answer (score 0):

The code for the add-to-cart button is in `templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variation-add-to-cart-button.php`, which is displayed in `<div class="single_variation_wrap" />`, line 53 of `templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php` by the Javascript fired by the dropdown.

You could move `<div class="woocommerce-variation-availability" />` from `variation.php` to under the button, but you'd need to find another way to bring the data to it.